# JAVA: jButton setBackground change on click event

Tags: java, swing, toggle, jbutton

I've been looking everywhere for a solution to my issue but haven't found anything that works:
REQUIREMENT: toggle between RED & GREEN background colours for jButton 'Colour!'

STATUS: When I click the button the first time, it changes to RED and does not change to GREEN on next click.

This is the code I have so far:

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
         Color colors[] = new Color[]
                {
                    Color.red, Color.green
                };
       for (int i = 0; i <= (colors.length-1); i++)
       {
        jButton1.setBackground(colors[i]);            
        }
```

UPDATE (solution):

```
 if (jButton1.getBackground() == Color.black || jButton1.getBackground() == Color.green)
       {
           jButton1.setBackground(colors[0]);
       }
       else
       {
           jButton1.setBackground(colors[1]);
       }
```

Comment: First of all, don't use a `MouseListener` on buttons, use an `ActionListener`, second of all, how do you determine the current state of the button in order to know which state you should change to?

Comment: So I need to `getBackground` prior to setting the colour?

Comment: adding `getBackground` prior to the loop or inside the loop change the button to GREEN.

Comment: There is no need for the loop ... kind of. You need to be able to find the index of the of the current color in the array and then determine which index to use next...

Answer (score 2):

Use an `ActionListener` instead of a `MouseListener` with buttons, a mouse isn't the only way a button can be triggered.

You need some way to know the current state of the button, for example, you could...

- check the current color of the button in a `if` statement and switch to the other color
- use a `boolean` value to switch between states
- use modular maths (I know scary)

For example...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private int clickCount = 0;

    public TestPane() {
        JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
        btn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btn.setBackground(Color.RED);
        btn.setOpaque(true);
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clickCount++;
                if (clickCount % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Red");
                    btn.setBackground(Color.RED);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Green");
                    btn.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                }
            }
        });
        add(btn);
    }

}
```

> The button starts off a (null) so the first click should change to RED, second to GREEN, third to RED, etc...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    protected static final Color[] COLORS = new Color[]{null, Color.RED, Color.GREEN};
    private int clickCount = 0;

    public TestPane() {
        JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
        btn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btn.setBackground(null);
        btn.setOpaque(true);
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clickCount++;
                switch (clickCount) {
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                        btn.setBackground(COLORS[clickCount]);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        add(btn);
    }

}
```

If you have more then two colors, then you could simply use

```
if (clickCount > 0 && clickCount < COLORS.length) {
    btn.setBackground(COLORS[clickCount]);
}
```

instead of the `switch` statement

Comment: if @Edgar wants to have many colors ie. Color[] , then he can replace if case with (clickCount % colors.length)

Comment: @SrinathGanesh Or possible use a `List`, but either will work ;)

Comment: The button starts off a `(null)` so the first click should change to RED, second to GREEN, third to RED, etc...

Comment: @SrinathGanesh I tried this and it didn't work; always stays at RED.

Comment: Okay, so use `btn.setBackground(null);` instead of `btn.setBackground(Color.RED);` and change the `if` statement to work with the `clickCount` value only, so when it's `1`, it's red, when it's `2` it's green and anything else becomes ignored

Comment: So, I basically had to set a default colour (e.g. black) and create an if statement that would check the colours set. See below...a bloated solution - thanks everyone!
       `if (jButton1.getBackground() == Color.black || jButton1.getBackground() == Color.green)
       {
           jButton1.setBackground(colors[0]);
       }
       else
       {
           jButton1.setBackground(colors[1]);
       }`

Answer (score 0):

```
jButton1.setBackground(Color.black);

private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
             Color colors[] = new Color[]
                    {
                        Color.red, Color.green
                    };    
    if (jButton1.getBackground() == Color.black || jButton1.getBackground() == Color.green)
               {
                   jButton1.setBackground(colors[0]);
               }
               else
               {
                   jButton1.setBackground(colors[1]);
               } }
```